# How does message-grouping impact distribution of the messages among concurrent consumers?

Tags: activemq-artemis

The picture below depicts my basic use-case using message groups and Spring-based JMS consumers.

Please note, here the concurrency refers to the config set as shown below:

```
defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setConcurrency("3-10");
```

[image: Msg-Grp with ANYCAST address]

- Would the G1 and G2 listener receive messages concurrently for the respective groups?
- Would in any case the message from one group wait for the dispatch of any message in another group?

Comment: @JustinBertram the message order is supposed to be as depicted in the queue. Please ignore the numbering the msg-label.

Comment: @JustinBertram I guessed that with topic, the address will distribute messages to multiple queues, but the messages belonging to a particular group will always go to the same queue and in turn same consumer

Comment: @JustinBertram if I understood correctly from your FIFO comment, it means that the ordering of messages will be preserved, but grouping will ensure that the messages that belong to the same group will always go to the same consumer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223766/discussion-between-arshal-jain-and-justin-bertram).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, multiple consumers receiving grouped messages can receive them concurrently. However, there are caveats...

The core JMS client implementations actually consumes messages from a *local* data structure that is filled with messages asynchronously based on the [`consumerWindowSize`](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/flow-control.html) which is 1 MiB (1024 * 1024 bytes) by default. If a consumer is receiving messages from a large, contiguous group and its "window" fills up then the broker will not be able to dispatch any more messages to it and will have to wait for the consumer to acknowledge messages in order to dispatch more. Once that block of grouped messages is dispatched then the broker will be able to dispatch messages from other groups to other consumers.

This is also explained in [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/message-grouping.html) (although in a bit less detail).

Comment: stompConsumerCredits in the stomp acceptor is to be used I suppose for this purpose

Comment: That's correct. The original question didn't mention anything about STOMP consumers so I didn't mention that.